# Convert sql code to linq (Inner join Query)

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, sql-to-linq-conversion

Could somebody help me please to convert this sql code to linq .

SQL query

```
select distinct  coursecode
from UnitSet_Unit  
where UnitCode  in ('FDFFSACA' ,'FDFFSCFSAA', 'FDFOPTHCP3A ')
and CourseCode in (Select  distinct  coursecode
                  from Trainee_course
                  where TraineeID =10000088 )
```

Where `UnitCode`  in `IN clause` come dynamic and in the form of array .
and the course code in the second part is also have variable count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head, assuming we have the following inputs (and you are working in C#):

```
var unitCodes = new List<string> { "FDFFSACA" ,"FDFFSCFSAA", "FDFOPTHCP3A" };
var traineeID = 10000088;
```

This should work:

```
var result = (from us in db.UnitSet_Unit
              where unitCodes.Contains(us.UnitCode)
              && us.CourseCode == (from tc in db.Trainee_course
                                   where tc.TraineeID == traineeID
                                   select tc.CourseCode).Distinct().SingleOrDefault()
              select us.CourseCode).Distinct();
```

Comment: Thank you DavidG. This help me to get the actual linq query.